# Deny overriding specific fields of a Pydantic model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

What is the proper way to restrict child classes to override parent's fields?

**Example**. I want this to fail:

```py
class TechData(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, alias='_id')

class Child(TechData):
    id: Optional[int]  # fail
```

I thought of creating:

```py
class TechData(BaseModel):
    _id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, alias='_id')

    @final
    @property
    def id(self) -> int:
        return self._id
```

But it seems to be possible only on dataclasses.

`BaseModel` checker fails with:

`Field name "id" shadows a BaseModel attribute; use a different field name with "alias='id'"`

Is there a way to keep `BaseModel` validation and serialization features and forbid overrides of a certain fields?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the most elegant solution would involve a custom meta class, but Pydantic models have their own [`ModelMetaclass`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.6/pydantic/main.py#L121), which is not exported publicly. Therefore I would not consider any implementation based on that meta class to be stable.

A workaround that does not involve the meta class may be to keep track of all the fields defined on the parent model(s) and hook into [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) to raise an error during subclassing, when one of them is overriden.

Here is an example implementation:

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import ModelField


class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):
    __parent_fields__: ClassVar[dict[str, ModelField]] = {}
    __final_fields__: ClassVar[set[str]] = set()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        for name in cls.__final_fields__:
            if cls.__fields__.get(name) is not cls.__parent_fields__.get(name):
                raise TypeError(f"The `{name}` field can not be overridden")
        cls.__final_fields__.update(kwargs.get("final", ()))
        cls.__parent_fields__ = cls.__fields__
```

Now you can specify fields to be considered "final", when you create a model by specifying them as an iterable of strings (the field names) in the `final` keyword argument of the class constructor like so:

```py
class Foo(CustomBaseModel, final=["y"]):
    x: int
    y: str


class Bar(Foo):
    x: str
    y: str
    z: bool
```

The result is an error:

```
...
TypeError: The `y` field can not be overridden
```

Notice that the error is being raised, despite the fact that the subclass changes nothing of substance about the `y` field (keeping the type the same, not specifying a default etc.). This is due to the **identity** check and is intentional here, but you could go about this differently, if you want.

The `__fields__` dictionary contains all the `ModelField` instances present on any given model, so you could compare the types only for example.

It may be worth mentioning that the Pydantic `ModelField` already has an attribute named `final` with a different meaning (disallowing reassignment). If that bothers you, you may want to change the terminology here to something like "fixed" or "forbidding_override".

---

### Alternative

If you do not like the interface of passing the field names to the class constructor, we could (ab)use the `extra` field keyword arguments like so:

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import Field, ModelField


class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):
    __parent_fields__: ClassVar[dict[str, ModelField]] = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        for name, field in cls.__parent_fields__.items():
            no_override = field.field_info.extra.get("no_override")
            if no_override and field is not cls.__fields__.get(name):
                raise TypeError(f"The `{name}` field can not be overridden")
        cls.__parent_fields__ = cls.__fields__


class Foo(CustomBaseModel):
    x: int
    y: str = Field(no_override=True)


class Bar(Foo):
    x: str
    y: str
    z: bool
```

Same error as before here.

Here, again, the name of the keyword argument `no_override` can be changed to whatever you find most appropriate. The other logic is the same.

This approach may be slightly less efficient because it needs to check *every* single model field, rather than just checking those in the `__final_fields__` set from above. But I suppose that will be negligible in most situations.

Also, `extra` field keyword arguments will appear on the model schema by default. So doing `print(Foo.schema_json(indent=4))` will give the following output:

```json
{
    "title": "Foo",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "x": {
            "title": "X",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "y": {
            "title": "Y",
            "no_override": true,
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "x",
        "y"
    ]
}
```

Not necessarily a problem, just worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
from  pydantic import Field, BaseModel, field_validator

class TechData(BaseModel):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, alias='_id')

    @field_validator('id')
    @classmethod
    def it_should_keep_the_parent_attrs(cls, v: int | None, info) -> str:
        if cls.model_fields["id"].is_required() is not False:
            raise ValueError("It should be optional.")
        if cls.model_fields["id"].alias != '_id':
            raise ValueError("Alias not _id.")
        return v


class Child(TechData):
    id: int


c = Child(id=2)  # fails
c = Child(_id=2)  # fails
```

You could still overwrite the validator, but it would need to be much more intentioned. You can also write validators that restrict the type. **The only problem here, is that the child defines a default value, and the value is not defined when validating the model, then the validator would not run? Perhaps using a model validator would actually be best.**

**Edit:**

Perhaps something like this would work better:

```
from typing import Any
from  pydantic import Field, BaseModel, model_validator

class TechData(BaseModel):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, alias='_id')

    @model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def id_should_keep_the_parent_attributes(cls, data: Any) -> Any:
        if cls.model_fields["id"].is_required() is not False:
            raise ValueError("It should be optional.")
        if cls.model_fields["id"].alias != '_id':
            raise ValueError("Alias not _id.")
        return data


class Child(TechData):
    id: int = Field(default=None)


c = Child(id=2)  # fails
c = Child(_id=2)  # fail
```

It should work, even if a default is defined.